# Импорт произвольного файла как модуля

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import

Я имею в виду, как можно реализовать импорт любого произвольного `.py` модуля на компьютере, будто бы этот модуль часть нашего проекта.

Допустим, у нас есть `D:\Modules\doit.py`. Надо реализовать импорт этого модуля. Сама собранная (при помощи pyinstaller) программа, которая вызывает этот модуль, может находиться где угодно. Конечно, она имеет права на чтение `doit.py`, проблема только в том, как его импортировать.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Можно добавить директорию, в  которой хранится модуль в список sys.path:

   ```
   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0, 'D:\Modules')
   import doit
   ```
2. Можно воспользоваться модулем [importlib.util](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly):

   ```
   import importlib.util
   spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location('doit', 'D:\Modules\doit.py')
   module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
   spec.loader.exec_module(module)
   sys.modules[module_name] = module
   import doit
   ```